Should the poster of a question be able to mark their self-answers after 2 days automatically?
After the poster finds an answer and posts it, they have to wait 2 days to mark it as the answer. Should Stack Exchange provide a button or option to automatically mark it as the answer after 2 days, instead of manually going back to the question 2 days later? That would require setting a reminder and the author may forget. If the answer works for the author, then is there an incentive for them personally to verify other answers?

You've posed a few questions, but I don't follow your argument. What would be the purpose of automatic acceptance - if an the top answer isn't the best solution, but the best solution isn't complete - there wouldn't be any reason to have bounties to attract better answers. Can you clarify your argument.

No. This is entirely against the point of acceptance, which was already a junk function anyway.


Provide a button or option to automatically mark it after 2 days.

This is a bad idea definitely. When you post an answer, you think it is good, then you set a reminder/button/option so that the system mark the answer as accepted.
But how do you know that there aren't other good answers? Or have you changed your mind about what a good solution to your problem is? Or maybe your answer isn’t that correct and needs some corrections?
To summarize, I don’t think that this is a good idea as adding this feature may cause more frustrations than benefits. This is not a good idea for sure.
Also, you should see here for the reason why OP needs to accept his/her own answer after 48 hours:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/
From the blog, it says that:


Wait 48 hours. You must wait 2 days from the time you originally asked your question before you can accept your own answer. This gives other users a chance to answer the question in good faith, and earn the accepted answer.




instead of manually going back to the question 2 days later

No, I will take some time to see old questions and check that whether there is a better solution/answer for a question. I think it is important to do that and consider the possibility that I might be able to get more information from a different answer.
